# How do I create a sub folder for every file I create dynamically?

Tags: java, file

Every time I create a file, I want it to do it inside a new folder with files name.

```
public void convertLocalSwaggerToAsciiDoc() throws IOException {
    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\jeff\\Desktop\\apidocs\\apidocs\\SwaggerJSON");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); //Makes an array of all the files

    int index, length = lengthOfFiles(listOfFiles); //lengthOfFiles counts number of files inside the folder

    for (index = 0; index < length ; index++) {
        Swagger2MarkupConverter.from(listOfFiles[index].getPath()).build().intoFolder("src/docs/asciidoc/generated/conversion");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If i'm reading your question/statement correctly it looks like you want to create different folders.

In Java, this can be achieved by creating an instance of a File-

```
File file = new File("path to new folder");
```

And then calling-

```
file.mkdir();
```

to achieve the creation of a new Directory.

** Edit **

Iteratively, do something like this-

```
for (each file in the list) {
   File folder = new File(path to parent folder + file.getName())
   folder.mkdir();
   File file = new File(folder.getPath() + currentFileName + currentFileExtension);
```

}

Comment: That makes a folder and then puts all the files in it. I want to make a separate folder every time it loops and stores the file in it. Do you how to do that?

Comment: So, you would want to employ the same strategy, but change the folder name for each iteration. Perhaps you could base your folder name off of the file name. If I'm reading your secondary question correctly, I edited the post above.

Comment: Please let me know if I answered the question for you.